# Execution_date in DockerOperator airflow

Tags: docker, airflow, dockeroperator

I have a docker container that parse audio files in text files via docker container that is to be mounted to the folder where these audiofiles are. I want to create an Airflow dag, that will to this task automatically.
There is my plan

1. I download audiofiles to the folder,that is names as execution_date,i.e. `/path/{{ds}}`
2. I run docker container through docker operator with `volumes = ['/path/{{ds}}']`
   The problem is that docker operator tries to find folder `/path/{{ds}}` without transforming `{{ds}}` into date and taking it as a string.
   How can i fix it? Thatks for helping

Answer (score 0):

volumes isn't a templated parameter.

You can overcome this by creating `MyDockerOperator` as:

```
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

class MyDockerOperator(DockerOperator):
     template_fields = ('volumes') + DockerOperator.template_fields
```

By doing so `MyDockerOperator` has all the functionality of `DockerOperator` with the additional support of `volumes` as templated parameter.